# Change the material displayed in the Node Editor from Python

Tags: python, materials, properties, operator

Would like to be able to change the material node displayed in the `Node Editor` from Python after running an operator to create a new material node in Python.  In the `Node Editor`, I can click "New" and have a new node created and displayed (see the image below).  I can also select which material to display.  Is there a way to do this from Python?

[image]

**Use Case**

I am linking the material from another `.blend` file and would like to display the new material in the editor so the user can immediately start working on it.  The new material node is not linked to any object by default, that is left up to the user.  The code looks like this:

```
with bpy.data.libraries.load(blend) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.materials = ['fancy material']
# Change the Node editor display to show the new node?
```

While trying to figure out how to change the displayed material node, I found this code that displays the `template_ID` but do not know how to change it display my new material nodes. (Edited for brevity)

```
class NODE_HT_header(Header):
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'

    def draw(self, context):
        snode = context.space_data
        # Custom node tree is edited as independent ID block
        layout.template_ID(snode, "node_tree", new="node.new_node_tree")
```

Realizing this isn't the best "blender" behavior, is it possible?

Comment: You'd like to assign an imported material to a object in your scene, right?

Comment: The node editor automatically shows the material from the selected object in the scene, so I think there is no need to write any node editor code. If there is a reason, please provide a **use case** and let me know what else you need - removed my answer.

Comment: @poor, added more details and a use case.  Basically, I want to change which material node is displayed in the editor from Python code.  Just the same as if I had clicked `New` or selected the material node.  Thanks!